# Chrome path to 256x256px icon of current Firefox build

Tags: firefox, path, firefox-addon, icons

Where can I find the 256x256px image of the Firefox logo in the Firefox build? For example I can find the 16, 32, 48, 64, 128px version at `chrome://branding/content/icon64.png`

The reason I am looking for the 256px version is because the `firefox.ico` file contains 16, 32, 48, and 256px images: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/branding/official/firefox.ico.

And I am taking the base PNG images and badging them and making my own icon container file.

PS: This file does not show link to 256x256 file: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/branding/official/content/jar.mn

But we see a default256.png exists in the official folder here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/branding/official/

Worst case, there is no Chrome path to the 256x256 image, so I'll find it online and pack it in my addon. But I don't know where to find these 256px images online either.